# iOS route-me draggable marker looses track (even in samples)

Tags: ios, objective-c, draggable, marker, route-me

In my iOS app I'm using the route me lib to display a map in offline mode.
I have some markers on the map, and now I would like to make them draggable. I used this code :

```
- (void) mapView:(RMMapView *)map didDragMarker:(HotspotMarker*)marker withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([[event allTouches] count] == 1 && touch.phase == UITouchPhaseMoved)
    {
        CGPoint position = [touch locationInView:[touch.view superview]];
        CGSize delta = CGSizeMake((position.x-(marker.position.x)),
                                  (position.y-(marker.position.y)));
        [marker moveBy: delta];
        [marker setProjectedLocation:[[_mapView.contents projection]
                                      latLongToPoint:[_mapView pixelToLatLong:marker.position]]];
    }
}
```

The markers drag well when I move the mouse slowly, but when I move the mouse a little quickly, I loose the track.

So I looked the sample "MapTestbedFlipMaps" project and run it... And encountered the same problem.

Then I tried to do it by myself with a gesture recognizer... but I still have the issue.

Any idea ?

EDIT : the problem doesn't come from the marker's image's size, I tried with a 100x100 image and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
- (void) mapView:(RMMapView *)map didDragMarker:(RMMarker *)marker withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint position = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:mapView];

    CGRect rect = [marker bounds];

    [self.mapView.markerManager moveMarker:marker AtXY:CGPointMake(position.x,position.y +rect.size.height/3)];

}
```